# django SelectDateWidget Years in reverse

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there a way in which you can get the "SelectDateWidget" to display the years in reverse or DESC order?

```
my_form_field = forms.DateField(widget=MonthYearWidget(years=range(2012,1970)))
```

Does not seem to work.

MonthYear widget is a smaller breakdown that only gives you the month and year

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `years=range(2012,1970,-1)` (note the -1 as the step/increment).